# System is unlocked on power up

Tags: security

Whenever I power up my system, I am automatically logged in. I never get prompted to type in my password. However, if I suspend the system (either from the power menu or by closing my laptop) I *do* get the password prompt.

In `System Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Locking` I have both options turned on.

How do I fix this? I expect a password prompt on power up.

**System info**

```
elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera
Built on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Linux 4.15.0-151-generic
GTK 3.22.30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `System Settings` -> `User Accounts`, and click your account, you'll see the option `Log In automatically`. Make sure it is disabled.

[image]

NOTE: You'll need to click the [image] button in order to make changes to your account.

Comment: It is already disabled.

Comment: Ok, this was a bit buggy but I disabled it, restarted, enabled it and then it worked as expected.